# SLF4J: Failed toString() invocation on an object of type [java.util.ArrayList]

Tags: java

Specific error message...

```
SLF4J: Failed toString() invocation on an object of type [java.util.ArrayList]
Reported exception:
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:675)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:208)
    at java.time.LocalDate.toString(LocalDate.java:2032)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.toString(LocalDateTime.java:1972)
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.toString(ZonedDateTime.java:2206)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.sxy.sibemanagementapi.domain.OrderInfoPassenger.toString(OrderInfoPassenger.java:734)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.sxy.sibemanagementapi.domain.OrderChangeIssue.toString(OrderChangeIssue.java:1398)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:300)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.sxy.sibemanagementapi.domain.OrderChange.toString(OrderChange.java:753)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.sxy.sibemanagementapi.domain.OrderChangeIssue.toString(OrderChangeIssue.java:1398)
    .
    .
    .
```

Potentially problematic code...

```
        List<String> ticketNo = new ArrayList<>();
        issueListCopy.forEach(item -> {
            ticketNo.add(item.getOldTicketNo().equals(null) ? item.getTicketNo() : item.getOldTicketNo());
        });
```

item.getOldTicketNo() and item.getOldTicketNo() are both String types,So how should I optimize this code?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What does line 1398 of OrderChangeIssue.java look like?  I'm not convinced that the issue is in the code that you've posted - the error message and the stacktrace both imply that there's infinite recursion happening.  A method somewhere is calling itself, then calling itself again, and again, and again, until you get a StackOverflowError.  To be more specific, I'm pretty sure there's an issue in the toString() method on the OrderChangeIssue class.

Comment: A typical error for this would be a bidirectional relationship. Object A has an Object B, Object B has Object A and both call each other's toString method.